# redirect multiple ip address ranges

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to be able to redirect multiple ip addresses to a specific page on my website.
the catch is i do not want a "full ip address" i only want to use a partial range.
see this "deny from" Example:

```
deny from 100.22.
deny from 100.44.
deny from 22.122.
instead of denying them, i want to redirect them to http://mysite/service/denied.shtml
```

I know this is not a regular method to redirect ip addresses,
I also know it will redirect many others that begin with those numbers, but I am ok with that. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this rule should work in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(100\.(22|44)|22\.122)
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite/service/denied.shtml? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks, so using your example would i need to use the `[OR]` when adding a new line or ip address or is it not needed.?

Comment: Actually `OR` is not needed since regex `|` (pipe) is being used here which does the ORing.

Comment: sorry to ask again, but how can i add this link `http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/` in place of the `http://mysite/service/denied.shtml?` thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile so can't edit the answer but you can just replace the mysite URL with your actual URL.

Comment: works perfect, i just had to remove the `?` to get it to work. i suppose the `?` was not needed since there was no index page on the link